# Is double <ESC> not mapable in VS Code?

Tags: vim, visual-studio-code

I am trying to rebuild my .vimrc in VS Code. Is it possible to map  to :w?

I plowed through the given examples on github. There is an example where ZZ is mapped to :wq. But the same script does not work for  in the settings.json

Code example given on https://github.com/VSCodeVim/Vim :

```
    "vim.normalModeKeyBindingsNonRecursive": [
        {
            "before": ["Z", "Z"],
            "commands": [
                ":wq"
            ]
        }
    ]
```

My adaptation, that does not work:

```
    "vim.normalModeKeyBindingsNonRecursive": [
        {
            "before": ["<ESC>", "<ESC>"],
            "commands": [
                ":w"
            ]
        }
    ]
```

I do have remapped the `:` command to `<space>` but even without it it's not working.

I hope anyone can help me. Even if it is a definite 'no way that's possible'

Answer (score 0):

from vim, i can only map double escape if i firstly map ESC to no operation

```
noremap <esc> <nop>
```

i hope this helps

Comment: thanks for the answer. I checked my .vimrc and I am able to map double escape directly without first mapping esc to noremap. I just say: `map <Esc><Esc> :w<CR>`

I am using vim under macOS in iTerm2 with zsh. Maybe it due to the setup